# What is the title of the book Sonya drops at the train station?

Tags: reference, props, a-man-called-otto

I couldn't make out the title of the book while watching *A Man Called Otto*, but the cover had a cat on it. The screenplay doesn't mention it either. The movie probably won't be available on streaming for several months, so I was wondering if anyone here knows what it was.

Comment: Hello and Welcome!  Do you remember what color the cover of the book was?

Comment: Was it this one? Cannot really make it out anyway - https://i.imgur.com/zIqZwRu.png "The Madness and her pants" ?

Comment: @steelersquirrel the background was black.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby that's the book, but I don't think that's the title.  I think there's a shot where Otto picks up the book from the ground that is clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the information you gave us and the picture:

1. the cat on the cover
2. the title than we can barely read

But the words seem to fit the title of a book that often has a cat on its cover. And the closest thing I can come to with this data is [The Master and Margarita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Master_and_Margarita) from Soviet writer Mikhail Bulgakov (1st published in English 1967). The manuscript was not published as a book until 1967, in Paris.

If she's reading in French, then the title would be: "*Le Maître et la Marguerite*" and it still would fit what we see on the image.

[Photos of the book and various covers](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+master+and+margarita)

Comment: The book title had a name: Marguerite or Margarita in the title. Both my wife and i are curious as to the full title of the book.

Comment: I had a hunch it could have been this one, based purely on the other answer (I don't know anything about the film), but wasn't directly able to find anything online. But the book features a cat (Behemoth), so it is indeed very likely this one.

Comment: I believe the version shown in the film is the paperback version of [this one](https://bookshopapocalypse.com/products/the-master-and-margarita-by-mikhail-bulgakov-first-book-club-edition-1967?variant=30455017635897) (the First Book Club edition). Everything seems to correspond except for the back, hence I think it's the paperback version, featuring additional information.

Comment: +1 Very good. I can see why I thought the last part looks like 'pants'. I was rather joking about the title though.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question with limited info!

Answer (score 2):

The book that Sonya drops at the train station is *The Master and Margarita*, as shown in this screencap of the relevant scene:

[image: A screencap of the relevant scene showing that the book title is The Master and Margarita. The cover of the book has a cat on it.]